# getResourceAsStream returning null

Tags: java, netbeans, jnlp

I've seen many other people ask this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797162/getresourceasstream-is-always-returning-null) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195445/eclipse-getresourceasstream-returning-null), but it seems that I have done everything necessary yet I still get null when using the getResourceAsStream() call.

In netbeans I dragged my image into my package and it shows up in the folder in which the source code and .class files are held. So I have:
src\com\myProject\ClassIMakeTheCallFrom.java
src\com\myProject\MyImage.png

also a similar structure exists in:
build\classes\com\myProject\ClassIMakeTheCallFrom.class
build\classes\com\myProject\MyImage.png

However when I make the call:

```
System.out.println(dolphinWater.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myImage.png"));
```

It comes out null. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the image in a jar? just saying "myImage.png" to me would look in the root directory and not in your package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either put the file directly in the src folder, not the package folder. Or use `getResourceAsStream("com/myProject/myImage.png")`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: I think you are missing a '/', it will work better with: getResourceAsStream("/com/myProject/myImage.png")

Comment: Not if "com" is at the root of the classpath.  No need for a '/'.  Won't work at all if that's not true, and a '/' won't help it.

Comment: @ashokramcse you know you could fix it yourself. this is a wiki