# Adding images to a Java project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, ide

I'm trying to add my java project in android studio. I got many [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626810/can-android-studio-be-used-to-run-standard-java-projects) & added my Project in Android studio.

Now i am unable to add the assets to my projects. So please help me to solve it

Thanks in Advance

**Structure**

[image]

**CODE**

```
    this.trayIcon = new TrayIcon(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.png")));
    this.trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
    this.trayIcon.setToolTip("Remot Server");
    this.trayIcon.setPopupMenu(menu);

    SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(this.trayIcon);
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
```

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661229/getresourceasstream-returning-null-despite-called-file-being-in-same-dir-as-clas

Comment: Thanks for the link. It doesn't work for me

Comment: what is this TrayIcon anyway and why do you need so complicated way with imputStreams?

Comment: You can learn at TrayIcon here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html

Comment: Added another possible solution

Answer (score 3):

If you refresh your project in the gradle view (the blue arrow) and AS mark it as a resource folder you should be covered. The other thing is the path: Your path should start with a slash `/` when using `Class.getResource()` because your image is in the root of the resource folder.

See the acccepted answer here: [Classpath resource within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900154/classpath-resource-within-jar)

Answer (score 2):

You `resource` directory is in a non-Android Studio standard location. My guess is that you haven't altered your Gradle file to try to include that directory.

Best would be to move the image assets into the standard location, so that the apk packaging routines know what to put where. While its a pain for existing projects the process is straight forward:

1. Create a new empty Android Studio generated app so that all of the configuration is up to date
2. Copy over the code and resources into the appropriate place.

Alternatively

You could try to add your resources from your Java project 
in your build.gradle (app):

```
android {
    ....
    sourceSets {
        main {
            // default is resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }
 }
```

But I haven't tried it with images.

More details here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure

Comment: I tried your solution. but it is still not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check following image.
[Add Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nfNv.png)

When you are going to use it in code, you can use following code
// for image in Activity 
   AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
   InputStream instr = assetManager.open("close_btn.png");
   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instr, null, options);