# Exported JAR unable to read local file

Tags: java, eclipse, file, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

My Java application has a local file called "classes" (a simple `List<String>`) in a top-level folder called "assets". When I run the code below from Eclipse, the file is read no problem.

```
try { // read in classes from local file
    ObjectInputStream inputStream =
            new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("assets\\classes".replace("\\", "/")));
    listOfClasses = (List<String>) inputStream.readObject();
    System.out.println("*** Reading local copy of classes file ***");
    inputStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

When I export my application as a JAR, and run it on a different computer, I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` on the 3rd line. I added the "assets" folder to the build path, so it should be in the JAR.

Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Whatever do you mean by exporting your program as a JRE? JRE generally stands for the program you use to run your java program, e. g. the `java` command is a part of JRE. I also fail to see what it has to do with `FileInputStream` which is just a plain old file reader that works the same as any kind of file-opening function.

Comment: "JRE" should be jar in question, and  `ObjectInputStream inputStream =
            new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("assets\\classes".replace("\\", "/")));` should be `ObjectInputStream inputStream =
               new ObjectInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/classes"));` in code, to work in a jar file as intended.

Comment: It's a JAR, not a JRE. Sorry about that. So yes, I go Export -> Runnable JAR file -> etc. `ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/asset‌​s/classes"));` however is giving a NullPointException when I fun in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileOutputStream` just opens a local file. It should be absolute (`/home/user/...` or `c:\temp\...`) or relative to the current directory. On Windows, for example, that's the directory containing the JAR, by default.

If you meant to package your `classes` file *into* the JAR, then you should use `getResourceAsStream`, as @guleryuz mentioned. The path should be either absolute starting from the CLASSPATH root (that is, the root of the JAR file), like `"/asset‌​s/classes"`, or (better) relative to the package of the calling class.

Speaking of classes, I'd strongly advise against using `getClass()` because it's a polymorphic method. There are two ways to get the class: by calling `getClass()` on an object or by accessing the static `class` “field”. If you have an instance of `MyClass` called `myObject`, then `myObject.getClass()` and `MyClass.class` are essentially the same thing. But! If your class is overridden by a class from another package, say, `TheirClass`, then, for an instance of `TheirClass`, `getClass()` will return `TheirClass.class`, even if you are calling `getClass()` from *your* code. So, unless your class is declared `final`, it is always a bad idea to use `getClass().getResource...` because you never know when someone overrides your class. And you're not supposed to know or even care!

Given all that, say, you have a class called `MyClass` in a package called `my.package`. The JAR could have the following structure:

```
my/
    package/
        MyClass.class
        assets/
            classes
```

Then, calling `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("assets/classes")` should do the trick. Alternatively, that could be `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/my/package/assets/classes")`. Note that the absolute path does *not* start from the project directory, where you may have `src` or `src/main` or whatever your build system uses. It is relative to the CLASSPATH root (that's right, the *absolute* path is *relative* to the CLASSPATH root, even if that sounds confusing). That is, it starts from the directory where your packages are.

The last, but not least, is that if you use Maven-like build system (Maven or Gradle, for example), then Java sources go to `src/main/java`, but resource files like your file go to `src/main/resources`. They end up in exactly the same place in your JAR file. That is, `src/main/java/package/MyClass.java` is compiled into `package/MyClass.class`, and `src/main/resources/package/assets/classes` go into `package/assets/classes`. But in order for the build system to figure out what to do with your files, you must place them into the right directories: `*.java` go to `java`, resources go to `resources`.

So, assuming Maven-like conventions, the project structure should be

```
src/
    main/
        java/
            my/
                package/
                    MyClass.java
src/
    main/
        resources/
            my/
                package/
                    assets/
                        classes
```

Given such a structure, you'll get a JAR file with the structure like above. Looks a bit crazy, but very useful once you get a hang of it.

If you're not using a Maven-like build system, then I have no idea how to configure Eclipse. Different IDEs may have their own conventions, and I've always used Maven with Eclipse. Some IDEs like to put Java sources and resources into the same directory tree, for example.

Comment: Getting closer. I've moved the file to MyProgram/src/resources/classes (I've unzipped the JAR and it's there) but `getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/resources/classes")` is returning null. (`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/src/resources/classes")` doesn't work either.) I don't have a class in "src" (they're all in "src/main") so how am I to not use `getClass()`?

Comment: This is frustrating. The problem with Eclipse is http://stackoverflow.com/a/2195501/852795. If I move the file to /src/main is works. BTW, if I move it /bin/main is also works. In any event, using `getRourseAsStream()` is the correct answer for the JAR, so I'll mark this 'accepted'. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark, see my edits about `getClass` and `.class`. You almost never want to use `getClass` for accessing resources because it can be overridden and just return a wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks. I've switched to MyClass.class. I've got the file to work, so now I'm working on doing the same thing with a folder of files. This is really nuts.

Comment: @Mark, as for `src/main`, see my edits about Maven and Gradle. I don't know whether you're using Maven/Gradle or not (maybe you should, that would solve a lot of problems like this!), but if you have `src/main/java`, then maybe you should have your resources in `src/main/resources`. Anyway, neither `src` or `src/main` should be present in the `getClass` call even if you use absolute paths, because they're *above* the CLASSPATH hierarchy, and absolute paths starts at the *same* level.

Comment: So I'd expect something like `src/main/java/my/package/MyClass.java`, `src/main/resources/my/package/assets/classes` and `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("assets/classes")` call. That would fit the usual pattern. At least that how Maven does things and that what most Java developers expect.

Comment: @Marc, see more edits about that (as it's considered a bad style to keep such things in comments).

Comment: For anyone who gets here, I got this working. I'm using Eclipse (no Maven or Gradle) so I moved all my files into src/main/resources (I created the folder) and then did `ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("classes"))`. I believe the `getClassLoader()` was the trick. Then `List<String> listOfClasses = (List<String>) is.readObject();` seems to work like a charm. Thanks for the help!